# Show for which $a \in {R} $ is $ f_a:\ \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 $ surjective

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing

Let $ f_a:\ \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 $ where $f_a(x, y) = (ax + y, (a + 6)x + ay)$.

**Assumption:**
Let's assume that $ f_a $ is surjective. Ergo, for every coordinate $ (u, v) $ in the output space $ \mathbb{R}^2 $ exists a coordinate  $ (x, y) $ in the entry space $ \mathbb{R}^2 $ such that $ f_a(x, y) = (u, v) $.

**Calculation:**
Let $ax+y=u$ and $(a+6)x+ay=v$. We can use these equations, and denote $y \rightarrow y=u-ax$, and plug it into the second equation $ax+6x-a^2x=v-au \rightarrow x=\frac{v-au}{a+6-a^2}$.

From that, we can say $a+6-a^2 \neq 0 $, or rather $(a-3)(a+2) \neq 0 $. Ergo $ a_1\neq 3 $, and $ a_2\neq -2 $.

**Proof by contradiction**: How would you construct such proof?

**My proof idea**: $\forall (u,v) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 \; \exists (x,y) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 | \; f_a(x, y)= (u,v) = (ax + y, (a + 6)x + ay)  $. Hence, the image of $ f_a $ has to be every element in $ \mathbb{R}^2 $. This is not true, since we showed that for $a_1, a_2$ we can find values of $(u,v)$ that are not directly related to $(x,y)$. Because for $a_1: 3u=v$ and $a_2: -2u=v$

Comment: Are you specifically seeking a proof by contradiction? In this case you've shown that for $a \not = -2,3$ you have surjectivity (since you can pick $(x,y)$ to get any $(u,v)$), so now it's enough to consider the cases of $a=-2$ and $a=3$ and see what happens

Comment: @George I'm not keen on contradiction. It was only an idea - might have not been the best. I'm new to writing proofs, therefore, I would appreciate if you could show me a better way of thinking about proof-writing for this specific example.

Comment: Ah yes I've just seen your edit - here I think your proof by contradiction isn't the easiest way of reasoning. Your last sentence is explicitly calculating the image of $f_3$ and $f_{-2}$. So for example for $a=3$ you can say $f_3(\mathbb R ^2) \subseteq \{(u,3u) \mid u \in \mathbb R\} \subsetneq \mathbb R^2 $ which is saying it's not surjective.

Comment: @George is there a better way to approach this proof? Perhaps, a completely different approach derived from the already made calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Was too long for a comment and seemed potentially more appropriate as an answer)

Yes, contradiction here isn't necessary and the proof can be more readable without it (it would still work in some ways though, might just be more complicated to phrase well):

Your calculation shows that for $a \not = -2,3$ we have that $f_a$ is surjective. (Since you have an inverse which given $(u,v) \in \mathbb R^2$, returns an $(x,y)$ such that $f_a(x,y) = (u,v)$.)

So then you're only left with those other cases (this is since just because the first idea doesn't work for $a=2,3$ doesn't necessarily mean there isn't another way). But then in your second part (the proof idea) you note that if $a=3$, then $f_a(x,y) = (3x+y,3(3x+y))$ and so $\mathrm{Im} f_3 = \{(u,3u)\mid u \in \mathbb R\}$ which is a line in $\mathbb R^2$, so $f_3$ isn't surjective (since the image isn't all of $\mathbb R^2$).

Then similarly for $f_{-2}$ you've shown the image is a line.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and explanation!